# xml::Twig and findnodes

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-twig

I have the following xml code snippet :

```
<a>
  <b> textb <b>
  <c> textc <c>
  <d> textd <d>
<\a>
<a>
  <b> textb <b>
  <c> textc <c>
  <d> textd <d>
<\a>
```

I use `xml::twig` to parse it as below :

```
my @c= map { $_->text."\n" } $_->findnodes( './a/');
```

and get the textbtextctextd as one element of the array. Is there an option to get with findnodes 
*textb,textc,textd* as 3 array elements and not one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the star at the end of the expression:

```
$_->findnodes( './a/*');
```

The '***' matches any tag, so you get the 3 child nodes - your current example only matches the 'a', and its text is the concatenation of the text of the nested elements.

Answer (score 2):

in XML::Twig 3.39 (and above) you can use [`findvalue`](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aTwig#findvalue-optional_array_ref-xpath-optional_offset-) to get an array of strings.

```
my @c = $_->findvalue('./a/');
```